# SMTP traffic timing out on my server

Tags: smtp, exchange-2003, port-forwarding

My mail server is not getting or processing incoming e-mails.  I recently changed my MX record to point to a different router on my network. I opened port 25 on the router and pointed it to my mail server.  No external e-mails are hitting it.  NETSTAT is showing the traffic reaching the server but it times out. Example: TCP    ML310DC:smtp           shvj2.jpmchase.com:27142  TIME_WAIT       0

I know E-mail is working on the server as internal e-mails are being  processed.

I have exchange 2003.

Comment: 1. Verifiy that the MX record points to a valid A record. 2. Verify that the A record resolves to the correct ip address. 3. If 1 and 2 check out then attempt to establish a telnet connection to port 25 of the MX record from outside your network.

Comment: What do you mean a valid A record.  I have it pointing to a static IP on my router.  I cheked it with Remote connectivity analyzer and got the following:

Comment: Test Steps 
   Attempting to resolve the host name xxx.xxxx.com in DNS. 
  The host name resolved successfully. 
   Additional Details 
  IP addresses returned: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
 
 Testing TCP port 25 on host xxx.xxxx.com to ensure it's listening and open. 
  The specified port is either blocked, not listening, or not producing the expected response. 
   
   Additional Details 
  The connection was established but a banner was never received.

Comment: MX records shouldn't point to ip addresses, they should point to A records. Your test would seem to indicate that connections to port 25 of the server are blocked. Are you sure that you have connections to port 25 of the router's ip address forwarded to the server?

Comment: Also, what is the domain name in question so that we can test your DNS?

Comment: I know the traffic is hitting the router but i dont think its getting to the server.  I'm not sure why.  Tee port shows open on the router via online port checker.  Not sure where is getting dropped.

Comment: If you can confirm in your router logs that the traffic is getting to it and not being dropped then the next step would be to verify that the port forwarding rule is correct. After that make a telnet connection to port 25 on the server from a computer on the same network. If that doesn't work then the problem is on the server, either the Windows firewall is blocking incoming connections or the SMTP service is down, or the SMTP virtual server is blocking the connections.

Comment: The funny thing is the traffic is hitting my server.  I checked with the netstat command but it reads;   TCP    ML310DC:smtp           shvj2.jpmchase.com:27142  TIME_WAIT       0
 TCP    ML310DC:smtp           correspondence.isecurus.com:3974  TIME_WAIT       0
 TCP    ML310DC:smtp           r33.us.neolane.net:64119  TIME_WAIT       0.  Its showing a timeout I believe.  I'm not sure whats causing the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

> The specified port is either blocked, not listening, or not producing the expected response.

This means that connections to port 25 on your external IP are not working.

One or more of the following could be wrong:

- You didn't do the port forwarding correctly
- The SMTP service on your Exchange server is not running
- You have IP filter rules on your SMTP service
- The firewall on your Exchange server is blocking SMTP
- Your ISP could be prohibiting you from running an SMTP server (which is common if you are using consumer class broadband)

Comment: 1) Port Forwarding is configured correctly.  verified via online port checker. 2) SMTP IS running on my server.  Nothing changed on it since I switched routers. 3) No filters on my SMTP services exist. 4? no firewall rules are on the server.  My ISP is blocking nothing.  We have business class connectivity.

Comment: Back to #1: Your comment above says the SMTP check tool you used said the port is closed.